# Best way to create a playlist of SpeechSynthesisStreams and play them using a MediaPlayer class?

Tags: c#, stream, uwp, media-player, speech-synthesis

It's insane. The MSDN documentation rarely mentions TTS, and when it does, it's just one/two paragraphs compared to 6 sections relating to Speech Recognition.

I'm trying to handle this scenario:

- The app loads a chapter `c` of story `s`;
- Chapter `c` is being split into `p[]` paragraphs;
- User taps the paragraph represented by a `TextBlock` control;
- The paragraph `p[x]` is being converted to speech and played using default audio output;
- in the `MediaPlayer_MediaEnded` event, next paragraph is being handled and prepared for playing, then played.

The thing is, with how I'm doing it right now, there are 4-8s gaps between paragraphs and that is not acceptable.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I'm using `Background Media Playback` with `MediaPlayer`. In `UWP8.1` this worked, but without BGAP and with `MediaElement` instead of `MediaPlayer` class.

Thank you!

## Edit

Here's how I have it set up right now:

***Reader.xaml.cs***

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth;
public int readerPosition = 0;
public async Task ReadParagraph(int id)
{
    var mp = (App.Current as App).mediaPlayer;
    var ns = (App.Current as App).nextStream;
    readerPosition = id;
    var tb = Items.OfType<TextBlock>();
    if(readerPosition < tb.Count())
    {
        if (synth == null)
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
        var whiteBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        if (readerPosition > 0)
            tb.ElementAt(readerPosition - 1).Foreground = whiteBrush;
        tb.ElementAt(readerPosition).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.AliceBlue);
        if (ns == null)
        {
            var str = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(tb.ElementAt(readerPosition).Text);
            var ms = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(str, str.ContentType);
            mp.Source = ms;
            mp.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 1.3;
            mp.Play();
            if (readerPosition + 1 < tb.Count())
            {
                var next = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(tb.ElementAt(readerPosition + 1).Text);
                ns = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(next, next.ContentType);
            }
            else ns = null;
        }
        else
        {
            mp.Source = ns;
            mp.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 1.3;
            mp.Play();
            if (readerPosition + 1 < tb.Count())
            {
                var next = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(tb.ElementAt(readerPosition + 1).Text);
                ns = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(next, next.ContentType);
            }
            else ns = null;
        }
    }
}
```

***MediaPlayer_MediaEnded***

```
private async void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    await Reader.Current.Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync(async (e) =>
    {
        await Reader.Current.ReadParagraph(Reader.Current.readerPosition + 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you load the next paragraph while the current paragraph plays instead of waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Currently I have it set up this way, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've updated the original post with the code I'm currently  using. Can you take a look at it?